# Change size of an NSView with center alignment constraints

Tags: cocoa, appkit

I have a view with "Center X Alignment" and "Center Y Alignment". How can I change the size of the view while still satisfying the constraints? If I use setFrame:, the view will be placed wherever the frame variable specifies, instead of respecting the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

There must be existing constraints which determine the view's size, or the view has intrinsic size. If you didn't add sufficient constraints, Xcode will add them for you, although it will generate warnings.

In any case, when using auto layout, `-setFrame:` is ineffective. The view's frame is simply changed back to whatever the constraints determine it should be on the next layout pass. If the constraints are ambiguous, the view's frame can end up with any of the possible values which are consistent with the constraints.

If you want to change a view's size, you need to modify the constraints which are determining its size.